# Failed to load resource - bootstrap error 403

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

Everything appears as normal, however when I inspect element in my checkout page I get the following errors showing up in the console

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/examples/navbar-static-top/navbar-static-top.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

My site has been set up for https, and I have tried the bootstrap links with and without the https: in the link.  I am new to this so it could be something silly, I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I have changed it so all the css and js are held within my static files and I am now getting the following errors;                                                                    GET https://mywebsite.com/static/css/bootstrap.min.css/ 
(index):22 GET https://mywebsite.com/static/css/navbar-static-top.css/ 
(index):28 GET https://mywebsite.com/static/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js/ 
(index):603 GET https://mywebsite.com/static/js/jquery.min.js/ 
(index):605 GET https://mywebsite.com/static/js/bootstrap.min.js/ 
(index):607 GET https://mywebsite.com/static/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js

Answer (score 1):

Here are the correct links, hope it helps
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/navbar-static-top.css
http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js

Comment: @jameslewis if you liked the answer please upvote, if this is the definite answer mark it. thanks

Comment: This would usually work however my css and js has to be served ovver https and this was what was causing the problems to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would donwload the files and I would upload it to my site. If the CDN has problems... your web will have it too...

I advise you to do it.

In addition, when I try to access to the links, I can't see the files too... You should use the links which @Lightwalker posted

I hope my answer will help you!